# Python processing the data and delay

Tags: python, sockets, kivy, python-multithreading

I developed a program to try to drive HMI when the touch controller is transmitting the touch coordinates data through socket. As you can see from the code below, **length** is the real time data I received and it's a list of strings displaying x,y,z coordinates. After the data is received, it is being processed I print the list to a txt file, then open the file and split the data. The problem is, after split operation, the data which I'm getting is no longer real time, there's a huge delay. For example, I compare the **"length"** and **"list"** by printing them in console in real time, and they don't match... Thanks in advance for the help!

Snippet of the socket_thread function:

```
def socket_thread():
    global X, Y, Xsave, Ysave
    PORT = 2001
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
    try:
        while True:
            s.sendall(b'true\n')
            length = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
            print(length, file=open("Eddie.txt", "a"))
            with open("Eddie.txt", "rt") as T:
                for buffer_line in T:
                    list = buffer_line.split('/')
                    if list[0] == 'True':
                        X = int(abs(round(float(list[1]))))
                        Y = int(abs(round(float(list[2]))))
            if not length:
                print("Recive_error\n")
                break
            len(length)
        s.sendall(b'end\n')
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        s.sendall(b'end\n')
a = threading.Thread(name='socket_thread', target=socket_thread)
a.start()
```

Comment: You are appending `length` to an existing "Eddie.txt", so that file keeps growing. Is that intended?

Comment: The file keeps growing correct. Well, the intend was to be able to receive the "real time" data, so is there an alternative way to do this? Thank you @tdelaney

Comment: I don't see where you are printing length and list to the console but the length and the last bit of list should match. The problem may be in `recv`. This thing seems to work by you sending "true\n" and then getting something back. You assume you get exactly the full response in a single recv, but TCP is a stream protocol with no guarantee of message boundaries. Is there something like a newline in the recv channel that lets you know when a message is complete? If so keep receiving til you see it. You may be sending more "true\n" than you should, and that in turn may be messing up the recv.

Comment: What is your objective in that method? every time you get something on the socket, you are opening the file `Eddie.txt` and appending what you received. Then you are opening that file again, reading the entire file, and closing it. Why are you re-reading the entire file each time you get a message from the socket?

Comment: @JohnAnderson John, the objective is to receive the data - length, then print the data to Eddie.txt file with real time coordinates data which received via socket. Then, open the Eddie.txt file and create a list (index), so I can separate X, Y, Z data, then I can read X, Y data and pass them to HMI GUI and actuate the HMI..

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for your feedback. As I'm new to Python, I'm not sure if I understand your explanation. So, there's a touch controller driver (written in C#) continuously sending the touch coordinates (as I touch the lens) data, I created a socket client to receive the touch data and send to the GUI script which written in Kivy. I'm sorry but could you further explain "newline in the recv channel that lets you know when a message is complete"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following method accomplish the same thing without constantly re-processing the entire file:

```
def socket_thread():
    global X, Y, Xsave, Ysave
    PORT = 2001
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
    try:
        with open("Eddie.txt", "a") as f:
            while True:
                s.sendall(b'true\n')
                length = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
                print(length, file=f)
                list = length.split('/')
                if list[0] == 'True':
                    X = int(abs(round(float(list[1]))))
                    Y = int(abs(round(float(list[2]))))
            if not length:
                print("Recive_error\n")
                break
            len(length)
        s.sendall(b'end\n')
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        s.sendall(b'end\n')
a = threading.Thread(name='socket_thread', target=socket_thread)
a.start()
```

Comment: John, I just tried, but I'm not getting any data somehow, I got the message "SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop". So I indented the "if not length:" statement and adjust the print and break accordingly. Not getting any data back.

Comment: You are amazing! Your method helped to resolve the issue!!!!! Thank you so much, however, now I encounter an issue, the text file is growing from 0kb to 25mb in less than probably 2 or 3 seconds... I don't know is there a way to clear the text file as I only need to "latest" coordinates data?

Comment: Do you really need the text file? You can just remove the `with` and `print` statements and it should still work (may need to adjust indentation).

Comment: John, no, the idea of creating the text file was to be able to obtain the list of data so I can use them to drive the HMIs.